# How to use a function or expression inside dplyr mutate on attributes of a t.test model created by formula call inside dplyr do?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
 library(dplyr)
 mtcars %>% 
 group_by(vs) %>% 
 do(tt=t.test(mpg~am, data=.)) %>% 
 mutate(t=tt$statistic, p=tt$p.value)
```

I have performed t.test on mgp with respect to am for each vs. I am trying to extract the attributes of the t.test model and arrange them in a data frame. I am able to extract p-value and t-value or any one-length attribute.

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
Groups: <by row>

vs         tt         t           p
1  0 <S3:htest> -2.579484 0.034481482
2  1 <S3:htest> -3.764735 0.004436935
```

Now, if I want to extract the mean group difference using the code below:

```
mtcars %>% 
group_by(vs) %>% 
do(tt=t.test(mpg~am, data=.)) %>% 
mutate(t=tt$statistic, p=tt$p.value, delta=diff(tt$estimate))
```

or even when I just want to access the mean of group 0

```
     mutate(t=tt$statistic, p=tt$p.value, delta=tt$estimate[0])
```

R throws the error below:

```
  Error: object 'tt' not found
```

It seems tt is evaluated in a different environment where it is not defined when an expression or function is applied on it. I tried using funs too but no success.
Could somebody please shed some light here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could extract it within the `do` without using any additional package.

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(vs) %>%
    do({
      tt=t.test(mpg~am, data=.)
      data.frame(t=tt$statistic, p=tt$p.value,delta=diff(tt$estimate)) 
    })
#     vs         t           p    delta
#  (dbl)     (dbl)       (dbl)    (dbl)
#1     0 -2.579484 0.034481482 4.700000
#2     1 -3.764735 0.004436935 7.628571
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `broom` package, which is made for statistical tests inside of data.frames:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(vs) %>%
           do(tidy(t.test(mpg~am, data = .))) 

Source: local data frame [2 x 9]
Groups: vs [2]

     vs  estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic     p.value parameter
  (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)       (dbl)     (dbl)
1     0 -4.700000  15.05000  19.75000 -2.579484 0.034481482  7.486364
2     1 -7.628571  20.74286  28.37143 -3.764735 0.004436935  9.017524
Variables not shown: conf.low (dbl), conf.high (dbl)
```